# Unable to Receive Events from Salesforce Pub/Sub API using Dart and gRPC

Tags: flutter, dart, salesforce, grpc, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to subscribe and listen to events from the Salesforce Pub/Sub API using Dart and gRPC. I've been able to successfully implement this in Python following the [quick start guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/guide/qs-python-quick-start.html), but I'm experiencing difficulties in Dart. Despite following a similar pattern, I'm not receiving any events in Dart while the Python script receives them in real time.

Here is the Dart code:

```dart
    import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
    import 'package:pubsub_testing/src/generated/salesforceProtoFile.pbgrpc.dart' as pb_grpc;
    import "package:pubsub_testing/src/generated/salesforceProtoFile.pb.dart" as pb2;
    
    // Session ID, instance URL, and tenant ID are provided.
    
    final authMetadata = CallOptions(metadata: {
      'accesstoken': sessionId,
      'instanceurl': instanceUrl,
      'tenantid': tenantId,
    });

    final channel = ClientChannel(
      'api.pubsub.salesforce.com',
      port: 7443,
    );
    
    final stub = pb_grpc.PubSubClient(channel);
    
    Stream<pb2.FetchRequest> fetchReqStream(String topic) async* {
      while (true) {
        yield pb2.FetchRequest(
          topicName: topic,
          replayPreset: pb2.ReplayPreset.LATEST,
          numRequested: 100,
        );
      }
    }
    
    Future<void> subscribe(String mySubTopic) async {
      print('Subscribing to $mySubTopic');
      try {
        final substream =
            stub.subscribe(fetchReqStream(mySubTopic), options: authMetadata);
        print("substream: $substream");
    
        await for (var event in substream) {
          print("Got an event!\n");
          if (event.events.isNotEmpty) {
            print("Number of events received: ${event.events.length}");
            var payloadbytes = event.events[0].event.payload;
            var schemaid = event.events[0].event.schemaId;
    
            var schema = await stub.getSchema(pb2.SchemaRequest(schemaId: schemaid),
                options: authMetadata);
    
            print("Got an event!\n");
          } else {
            print("[${DateTime.now()}] The subscription is active.");
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('An error occurred during subscription: $e');
      }
    }
```

The code runs without throwing an error, and it seems to successfully subscribe because the terminal does not close, indicating that it's waiting for events. However, no events are being printed to the console, even though I know they are being published because my Python script is receiving them.

I've checked the permissions, and the session ID I'm using has the necessary permissions to subscribe to the topic.

Does anyone have experience with this type of situation or could suggest possible solutions? I would appreciate any insights or assistance.

The following is the Python implementation that works(Of course I removed sensible info). Also, I commented out some lines such that I made the code as minimal as possible so it would be easier to replicate in Dart. This file works and receives events in real time:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
# import grpc
import requests
import threading
import io
import pubsub_api_pb2 as pb2
import pubsub_api_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc
# import avro.schema
# import avro.io
import time
import certifi
import json

semaphore = threading.Semaphore(1)

latest_replay_id = None

# with open(certifi.where(), 'rb') as f:
#     creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(f.read())

with grpc.secure_channel('api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443', grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(None)) as channel:



    # Store Auth 
    sessionid = ''
    instanceurl = ''
    tenantid = ''
    authmetadata = (('accesstoken', sessionid),
    ('instanceurl', instanceurl),
    ('tenantid', tenantid))
    
    # Generate Stub
    stub = pb2_grpc.PubSubStub(channel)

    # Subscribe to event channel
    def fetchReqStream(topic):
        while True:
            semaphore.acquire()
            yield pb2.FetchRequest(
                topic_name = topic,
                replay_preset = pb2.ReplayPreset.LATEST,
                num_requested = 1)
    
    # Decode event message payload
    def decode(schema, payload):
        schema = avro.schema.parse(schema)
        buf = io.BytesIO(payload)
        decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(buf)
        reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
        ret = reader.read(decoder)
        return ret

    # Make the subscribe call
    mysubtopic = "/event/RS_L__ConversationEvent__e"
    print('Subscribing to ' + mysubtopic)
    substream = stub.Subscribe(fetchReqStream(mysubtopic),
            metadata=authmetadata   )
    for event in substream:
        if event.events:
            semaphore.release()
            print("Number of events received: ", len(event.events))
            payloadbytes = event.events[0].event.payload
            schemaid = event.events[0].event.schema_id
            schema = stub.GetSchema(
                    pb2.SchemaRequest(schema_id=schemaid),
                    metadata=authmetadata).schema_json
            decoded = decode(schema, payloadbytes)
            print("Got an event!", json.dumps(decoded), "\n")
            # print(f"payloadbytes: {payloadbytes}")
            # print(f"schemaid: {schemaid}")
        else:
            print("[", time.strftime('%b %d, %Y %l:%M%p %Z'),
            "] The subscription is active.")
        # latest_replay_id = event.latest_replay_id
```

Comment: Mostly unfamiliar with Dart but very familiar with gRPC. It would be helpful to include the Python code and the Dart logs. I think (!?) you can use the [gRPC Environment Variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md) with the Dart implementation (perhaps `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG`).

Comment: I edited in the post my Python implementation.

Comment: I don't have a Salesforce developer account so it's difficult to repro your issue. I've a gRPC Health Checking protocol implementation that I deploy daily as part of a broader service. I'll write a Dart client for it (it has a streaming component) to see if I can help work out what's not working with your code.

Comment: That would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: OK. I struggled with a simple unary RPC call but now it's working for unary and server streaming. I followed the Dart gRPC Route Guide client [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/example/route_guide/) which has examples of unary and server streaming. Your code takes a slightly different approach and it's unfamiliar to me. Have you tried using the Route Guide example as a guide?

Comment: I'm unsure how your client invokes the gRPC request. In the Route Guide example, the client is wrapped in a `main` which calls a `runXXX` method which invokes the gRPC method.

Comment: Oops yeah, I should clarify... This whole test project is a dart CLI program. So I have another file that calls this `subscribe` method and passes in the topic. I already took a look at the Route Guide example but never really based myself on it, so I will try this.

Comment: I reimplemented my code using your pattern and my client continues to work. At this point, being unable to access the Salesforce endpoint, I'm unable to help.